# Power Query Concatenate list values from record without expanding to rows

Tags: powerquery

I have an API JSON response that provides some company data.  It includes a list of Company IDs and a record for sic_codes which is stored as a list (as there can be many sic codes for one company)

Currently, I'm expanding the values to rows and then using a custom column to group and combine them into a format like "sic1, sic2, sic3"

Is there a way to create this concatenated column without first expanding the rows?

here's a preview of the data:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
#"Transform" = Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStepNameGoesHere",{{"sic_codes", each try Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(", ")(List.Transform( _ , each Text.From(_))) otherwise null }})
```

or

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStepNameGoesHere, "expanded_SICs", each try Text.Combine(List.Transform([sic_codes], each Text.From(_)),", ") otherwise [sic_codes])
```